# Batch rename multiple files in multiple folders in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, rename

I want to batch rename files in multiple directories (20 directories, in each directory 20 files) and I want to each file get prefix of its folder name.

I can do this for single directory with this code:

```
dir | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Directory.Name + "_" + $_.Name}
```

But how to apply this for all folders and files in them?

master folder

- folder1

  - file1
  - file2
- folder2

  - file1
  - file2

desired output:

master folder

- folder1

  - folder1_file1
  - folder1_file2
- folder2

  - folder2_file1
  - folder2_file2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can simply add `-Recurse` to Recurse through the directories (also thanks to @infosecb for pointing out to also add `-File` switch to only rename files, not directories):

```
Get-ChildItem * -File -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Directory.Name + "_" + $_.Name}
```

Comment: Note adding the `-File` switch did not work for me. I believe the reason is that the file type in my folders was probably not recognized by PowerShell as being a file (proprietary file type) and therefore it did not rename my files. I therefore removed the `-File` switch, luckily for me I did not have sub-folders in each.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to HAL9256's suggestion, you should include the `-File` switch in the Get-ChildItem cmdlet to only select files.